# japanese and portuguese languages cannot support

Tags: php

My site Japanese supported. But Portuguese  language cannot fully display

Display on In�Cio Sobre N�S.

I have use for

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
```

this only Japanese language support.

I need to both languages (Japanese and Portuguese) should be display.

I need to helper for best solution.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to use Portuguese enocded

Answer (score -1):

You need to encode your file it must be same as your header and charset of Portuguese is that:

```
Portuguese charset=iso-8859-1
```

You need to set the meta for Portuguese language as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

**Side note:** 
Make sure your file also encoded as same your meta.

Comment: I have also using this (Portuguese charset=iso-8859-1) but cannot Japanese language support.

Comment: @Renukas: than apply condition on it, if japense page hit use japense,else portuses

Comment: I have same page display on Japanese and portuses language. how to ?

Comment: @Renukas: r u using PHP?

Comment: @Renukas: what are your urls of both language??